# Integrating Google Cloud Storage in an Android app

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I have spent over 2 days reading over the documentation over at Google Cloud Platform to find out how to hook up my Android app to my Google Cloud Storage.

I don't know if it's just the documentation that's just bad or my lack of understanding but I have really not gotten any closer in implementing this. **By contrast I remember it took me a couple of hours implementing Amazon S3 support in an earlier Android project so I'm not a complete idiot.**

**My requirement:**
Upload images to my GCS account

**Questions:**
Is there a simple "Hello World" type of example for hooking up an Android app to GCS?
I don't need access to users data so does that mean that I don't need OAuth 2.0?

Thanks

Comment: Were you ever able to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use app engine and can use cloud end points to build your application. Detail procedure for creating android app and using app engine as back-end are described [here](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/endpoints-androidconnected-gae) and [here](https://cloud.google.com/developers/articles/how-to-build-mobile-app-with-app-engine-backend-tutorial/)

Comment: Thank you for your response but I was looking for more of a specific example that shows how to connect your app to Google Cloud Storage. I am already aware of Google End Points but I haven't seen an example where they show how to create annotations for Google Cloud Storage. Honestly I am really close in finding a solution just by using the Java libraries but am having issues with authenticating the api requests.